# How to take arbitrary path in directory to see if file exists in python

Tags: python, file, directory

I want to take an arbitrary path to a file to see if it exists inside of a file path. I know this file does exist.

```
string = r'pathos/.*_cube/uni/ToolSub.pm'

result = os.path.isfile(string2)

print (result)
```

The directory of .*_cube is 'llb_cube" for me. However it can vary for each person testing the code for one person it may be "gfs_cube" and another 'hgf_cube" therefore I want to keep this directory arbitrary.

My problem is I cannot find a way for my program to comprehend that I want it to read an arbitrary string prefix at _cube (allow any characters before _cube). It keeps saying it does not exist but when I hard code the file to

```
string = r'pathos/llb_cube/uni/ToolSub.pm'
```

It returns true and it exists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is your string coming from when it is not hard-coded?

Comment: Neither python nor the OS knows how to interpret a wildcard (the `*` operator). That is typically something the shell program (think traditional bash or something like zsh) or a library (`glob` for python) would handle.

Comment: @Aaron what operator should I be using before "_cube" in order to assure that it is being read as an arbitrary string?

Comment: @FranceMadrid There is no such thing as an arbitrary string for the `os` library (There may be a counterexample, but in general). You need a library like `glob` as suggested by kabanus in the answer down below. It's easy to forget that a true operating system terminal is even more stripped down than something like bash or zsh which does things like searching for wildcards for you.